# Spring Security Custom Header Request Matcher Not Working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a requirement where using spring security I want that if a request of any type contains a particular header with a particular value then only it should be allowed to access the api's otherwise not. Below is my configuration code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    public AppSecurityConfig() {
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void configure​(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(new CustomHeaderRequestMatcher()).permitAll();
    
    }

}
```

Below is the customer header request matcher business logic:

```
public class CustomHeaderRequestMatcher implements RequestMatcher{

    public CustomHeaderRequestMatcher() {
    
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if(Objects.nonNull(request.getHeader("my-token"))
                && request.getHeader("my-token").equals("abc")) {
            System.out.println("true");
            return true;
        }
        System.out.println("false");
        return false;
    }

}
```

But here I could see that even when I am not passing the custom header "my-token" in my request it is allowing to access the api. For every request though custom request matcher class is being called. I am confused as to why spring security is not handling the case?

Comment: you have not blocked all other requests. spring sees the first rule and doesn't know what to do next. you could add a "anyRequest().denyAll()" or "anyRequest().authenticated()" after the "permitAll()"

Comment: Mnay thanks yeah as you said i was not handling negative scenarios where the request header is not sent then how to handle those requests :)

Answer (score 2):

you have not blocked all other requests. spring sees the first rule and doesn't know what to do next. you could add a "anyRequest().denyAll()" or "anyRequest().authenticated()" after the "permitAll()"